# Difference-in-Difference with Logistic Regression, how to add mutliple fixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I'm using `R` and running a **Difference-in-difference (DID) regression with unbalanced panel data**. Since my dependent variable is a dummy variable (Government officials originated from A or B), my DID is therefore a **DID with logistic regression**, and I can run the DID (by adding an interaction term of the two binary variables, "treatment(1) or reference group(0)" and "before(0) and after(1) the treatment", to the function, which is the DID estimator then) with `glm` package.

I am now trying to add **time fixed effect and county fixed effect** simultaneously to the regression.

I found in R we have a package called `alpaca` to do this. When I try to run a simple regression with `feglm()`, it runs smoothly, but when adding the interaction term (the DID estimator), it cannot work and shows `Error in qr.solve(MX * w.tilde, Mnu * w.tilde, epsilon) : singular matrix 'a' in solve`.  The function I use is basically the same as the one I used in `glm`.

I'm wondering whether you have any suggestions to figure out what's wrong.

Also, do we have any other good ways to deal with a "**DID logistic regression with two-way fixed effects**" in R?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need logistic regression for a binary outcome. You can use a linear probability model. As long as you use a robust standard error (which you should with country fixed effects anyway), the standard errors will be valid.

Comment: @Noah Thank you, Noah!  I've never heard of the "linear probability model" before; it looks very useful!  Thank you very much for your advice!  Have a nice one!